# Batch resized images on server, now image sizes are wrong in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I ran a Mogrify script on my server and resized about 1000 images. That went fine.

However when I started editing pages in Wordpress I noticed the images all looked very odd. Thumbnails for example weren't sized correctly and looked like they had been resized incorrectly.

I checked some images in the media library and saw that their metadata showed the old resolution, before I had resized it.

Is there any way I can have Wordpress go through and update its media library with the correct image sizes?

Comment: There's a lot you can do, but no quick fix or direct plug-in afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is WordPress has its own way of dealing with image sizes. And it's not only the metadata and other database info, the various versions that WP generates has the size suffixed to the file name.

You will probably need to use `add_image_size` in your theme's functions.php and/or adjust the Media Settings in the administrative panel.

After that, run the plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/regenerate-thumbnails). And regarding its name, I'll quote the plugin author:

> Anything that is not the fullsize image is a thumbnail. Some
>   thumbnails are just bigger than others. My plugin re-makes all of
>   them.

*PS: please note that WordPress questions are better fit here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com*